# Android Studio returning Transform Exception error when I try to run on an emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have spent the past 3 hours looking up similar questions and I feel like I have tried everything, to no success. I am trying to run an app through an emulator but it keeps returning a `'transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'` error. The program builds with no errors its just when I run it through an emulator that it causes me problems. Below is my app gradle as well as the error message:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.moa.gsrental.rentalinventory"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

}
```

Error Message:

```
Preparing output jar [C:\Users\Omar\AndroidStudioProjects\Rentalinventory\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar]
Copying resources from program jar [C:\Users\Omar\AndroidStudioProjects\Rentalinventory\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar]
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have resolved the issue but I have no idea how. I essentially just opened up sample code of a different android studio project and mimicked the build.gradle. Thank you to everyone who looked at my question!